# Can I use html5 local storage for storing user authentication session information

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, local-storage, passport.js

QUICK BACKGROUND:

I'm writing a Mongo/Express/Angular/Node SPA and using passport I have setup OAuth log in options to handle the user authentication / authorization.

With passport I am successfully maintaining session on the server, so all my XHR requests (that need it) are checking for a logged in user.

On log in the server puts the basic user session info into a cookie for the client to find on the authorization callback, I then am using angular-cookies' $CookieStore to access that cookie on the client save it to the rootscope and clear the cookie.

PROBLEM:

This is working perfectly except for any event where the user refreshes the browser, which causes my rootscope session to obviously get wiped.

So I was considering storing session information in the browser local storage (using store.js) then even on the initial load I could check for the session existing in the browser local storage and bypass the OAuth login if there was already a session.

**Is it bad practice or is there some logistical/security problems with storing user session information in the browser local storage?**

This app doesn't have any senstive data, sign up is free and logging in is really only there so I can track users and store data created in the application for each user.  And the user session would never have a password (I only allow OAuth login no local option).

Comment: depends. but make sure i cannot modify my local storage to create a valid login on your site. that would be nasty.

Comment: i would only store a session id and that i would probably store in a cookie.

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen Is a cookie a better option because of the ability to go in and modify objects in the localstorage?

Comment: no but it works everywhere and is a tried option for storing sessionid's, the security doesnt come from the cookie but from just storing a sessionid and not all the login information.

Comment: If you HAVE to store stuff in localstorage and it is vulnerable to modification, you could cryptographically sign it before storing, then check the signature when loading. but it is easier to just store the sessionid.

Comment: Would storing a sessionID be equivalent to storing an authToken that expires ? Is that sessionID just checked against a list on the server to determine validity?

Comment: This is strange. I've used an almost identical setup and have not had issues like this. Refreshing the site doesn't cause the user to log out. Closing the window and re-opening it does however.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of the `localStorage`, look at `sessionStorage` object: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

It works exactly like `localStorage`, but the whole `sessionStorage` object will be deleted when the browser window is closed - but will survive any page refreshes. It is an ideal place for storing session ids and alike.

But be warned that the `sessionStorage` is isolated within a browser tab - that means if your user choses to open a link in a new tab, the `sessionStorage` for that will be initialized empty.

Comment: What about autologin? Or persistent login?